# Vista -> Delete a file -> "Deleting 1 item" dialog stays on screen

Tags: windows-vista

Every now and then when I try to delete a file in Vista I get the message

```
"Deleting 1 item"
```

or

```
"Recycling 1 item"
```

It's a small dialog box that stays visible until I restart the computer.

**After I restart I am able to delete the file successfully but not before.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it's not as bad as a message I once had, which said there wasn't enough disk space to *delete* a file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you up to date?

There were some nasty hangs on file operations in Vista RTM that were generally sorted and are better by Service Pack 2.

To see what you are using, hold down the Windows Key and R, and type Winver, and read what it says the version number is.

Comment: You're right. I'm on 6.0 Build 6001 Service Pack 1. I thought I was getting the updates automatically. I guess not.